# How to initialize Gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs

I am starting a new project and would like to setup Grunt.js. Is there a particular command that will initialize a Grunfile.js with the boilerplate code structure?

Answer (score 17):

Grunt has its own set of [init plugins](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding#installing-templates) for use with [`grunt-init`](http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding).

From the docs, some of the officially maintained plugins include

> A few grunt-init templates are maintained officially:
>
> - [grunt-init-commonjs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-commonjs) - Create a commonjs module, including Nodeunit unit tests.
> - [grunt-init-gruntfile](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntfile) - Create a basic Gruntfile.
> - [grunt-init-gruntplugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-gruntplugin) - Create a Grunt plugin, including Nodeunit unit tests.
> - [grunt-init-jquery](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-jquery) - Create a jQuery plugin, including QUnit unit tests.
> - [grunt-init-node](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-init-node) - Create a Node.js module, including Nodeunit unit tests.

If those don't suffice, [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) also provides project scaffolding as well

Comment: Wishing to create a clean node project scaffold with Gruntfile and command line tools setup, then yeoman node generator is a nice choice. npm install -g yo, followed by npm install -g generator-node, followed by (from your project base) yo node.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at [`yeoman`](http://yeoman.io/).

It has generators and templates for creating various type of JS applications (from your own webapp to angular). It will create a base `Grunt.js` for you and can use Bower to manage dependencies.

Comment: yeoman generators don't require you use Grunt.  It's just a common practice.  In fact I got to this question because a yeoman generator I was using didn't use Grunt and I want to add it.